# Removing matrix elements under a certain value

Tags: r, matrix, genetics

I hava a matrix with dimensions below, the matrix contains calculated distances between a set of genetic variants, I would like to create a new matrix or modify the PosDiff matrix to only distances that are less than or equal to 500,000.

```
dim(PosDiff)
[1]   597 41099
```

i have tried `subset()`, `setdiff()` and get wonky results such as a matrix with 1 column and a 41099 observations

Thanks

Comment: can you post an example of the desired output?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please give us more information when you post a question so that we can reproduce the issue. What about trying `PosDiff[which(PosDiff<=500000)]`?

Answer (score 0):

Ok let's have a go

```
# Generate a random matrix with 4 rows and 3 cols
> m <- matrix(runif(12), nrow=4)
> m
#           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
#[1,] 0.62361346 0.7793682 0.9447203
#[2,] 0.14844661 0.7335280 0.2936238
#[3,] 0.08026447 0.8172304 0.1490721
#[4,] 0.46406955 0.1701625 0.7193786

# Then keep all the elements <= 0.5 setting all the rest to NA
> m1 <- apply(m, FUN=function(x){ifelse(x<=0.5, NA, x)}, MARGIN = c(1,2))
> m1
#           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
#[1,]         NA        NA        NA
#[2,] 0.14844661        NA 0.2936238
#[3,] 0.08026447        NA 0.1490721
#[4,] 0.46406955 0.1701625        NA
```

If you just want only the values less than `0.5` then you can run `m[which(m<=0.5)]`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need:

`ifelse(PosDiff <= 500000., PosDiff, NA)`

or:

`ifelse(PosDiff <= 500000., PosDiff, 0)`

dependently on whether you want to have missing value or 0 instead of elements which are greater than 500000.